# How to connect SOAP server and JSON client through Spring Integration?

Tags: java, json, soap, spring-integration

Good day. I am new to spring integration. I wrote a simple SOAP server, and I need to connect a client that communicates through JSON and a server that communicates via SOAP, but I’ve got confused in the technology that this framework provides. As I understand it there are JsonToObjectTransformer and ObjectToMapTransformer transformers. As I understand it is necessary to transform the data before transmitting it to the controller. Is it possible to do this with the help of transformers, or I can use other technologies in the spring integration. And can this be done only with the help of DSL?

Controller:

```
@Endpoint
public class CityEndpoint {
    private static final String NAMESPACE_URI = "http://weather.com/senchenko";
    private CityRepository cityRepository;

    @Autowired
    public CityEndpoint(CityRepository cityRepository) {
        this.cityRepository = cityRepository;
    }

    @PayloadRoot(namespace = NAMESPACE_URI, localPart = "getCityRequest")
    @ResponsePayload
    public GetCityResponse getCityResponse(@RequestPayload GetCityRequest request){
        GetCityResponse response = new GetCityResponse();
        response.setCity(cityRepository.findCity(request.getName()));
        return response;
    }
}
```

Config:

```
@EnableWs
@Configuration
public class WebServiceConfig extends WsConfigurerAdapter {
    @Bean
    public ServletRegistrationBean messageDispatcherServlet(ApplicationContext applicationContext) {
        MessageDispatcherServlet servlet = new MessageDispatcherServlet();
        servlet.setApplicationContext(applicationContext);
        servlet.setTransformWsdlLocations(true);
        return new ServletRegistrationBean(servlet, "/ws/*");
    }

    @Bean(name = "city")
    public DefaultWsdl11Definition defaultWsdl11Definition(XsdSchema citySchema) {
        DefaultWsdl11Definition wsdl11Definition = new DefaultWsdl11Definition();
        wsdl11Definition.setPortTypeName("CityPort");
        wsdl11Definition.setLocationUri("/ws");
        wsdl11Definition.setTargetNamespace("http://weather.com/senchenko");
        wsdl11Definition.setSchema(citySchema);
        return wsdl11Definition;
    }

    @Bean
    public XsdSchema citySchema() {
        return new SimpleXsdSchema(new ClassPathResource("xsd/weather.xsd"));
    }

    @Bean
    @Transformer()
    JsonToObjectTransformer jsonToObjectTransformer() {
        return new JsonToObjectTransformer();
    }

    @Bean
    @Transformer()
    ObjectToMapTransformer objectToMapTransformer(){
        return new ObjectToMapTransformer();
    }
}
```

**Addition**

I solved the problem with redirection to SOAP, but still do not know the best way to convert JSON into an SOAP Envelope and back.

```
@Bean
    public IntegrationFlow httpProxyFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Http.inboundGateway("/service"))
                .transform(t -> TEST_ENVOLOPE)
                .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8"))
                .handle(Http.outboundGateway("http://localhost:8080/ws")
                        .expectedResponseType(String.class))
                .transform(t -> TEST_RESPONSE)
                .get();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear or you are not fully familiar with technologies you need to work.
The *SOAP* is fully about XML messages exchange. On the server side you have a specific `MessageDispatcherServlet` which converts an incoming HTTP request to the SOAP envelop fully in XML. There is just nothing about JSON at all.

Your `CityEndpoint.getCityResponse()` is triggered by the Spring WS Framework when an incoming SOAP request is unmarshalled from the XML into the domain model via JaxB according your XSD definition and generated model. There is just nothing about Spring Integration at all.

Your `JsonToObjectTransformer` and `ObjectToMapTransformer` just don't make any sense in this scenario. They are not involved in the SOAP request process.

Sorry to disappoint you in my answer, but it even not clear by your question how that JSON client is going to call SOAP service when JSON and XML are fully different and not compatible protocols.

Comment: Sorry, I mean the client sends a request to the integration; the integration accepts the request, sends it to SOAP, receives the response, converts it to json and sends it to the client. It will probably be necessary to pack it in an envelope before handing it to the controller.